# html2canvas not working after hosting on godaddy

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i use html2canvas to generate my table as pdf, when i run on my visual studio, it works fine, but after i publish on godaddy, first javascript pop up message appear, but the pdf never downloaded, my adblock plus is disabled and i using chrome and edge to access it, by the way this is also my first time to hosting a web

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style.css" />
    <script src="jsfiles/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsfiles/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function Export() {
            alert("Sabar Ya!!!");
            html2canvas(document.getElementById('perubahantarif'), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                    var docDefinition = {
                        content: [{
                            image: data,
                            width: 500
                        }]
                    };
                    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("APPEM.pdf");
                    alert("Mendownload");
                }
            });
        }
//my table id
<table id="perubahantarif">

//my button
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" onclick="Export()" class="auto-style2" />
```

i put all of them inside the same aspx page

i expect the pdf will downloaded like in my local visual studio
the error is that pdf never downloaded when i publish to godaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after you updated question and comments, your src attribute works fine
when you are doing locally.

So you need to change them to current directory path, so use these changes in code
(a dot forward slash prefixed)

```
<script src="./jsfiles/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./jsfiles/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/js.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry, i already edit that, but the thing is that code runs perfectly on my local machine, but when i publish it, i only get this `alert("Sabar Ya!!!");` and the pdf never downloaded

Comment: oh thanks mate, looks like my js file not get published along with the others

Comment: aa ha let me update the answer and accept it if works